# Vaadin 23 add the common part of several Views into content part of AppLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I have `MainLayout` defined (extended from `AppLayout`), where I have configured `Header` and `Drawer`. Also, I have 3 different views which use `MainLayout` via `@Route` annotation.

There is some similarity between such 3 views - they have the common tabs at the top of the content area. Is it possible somehow to add such tabs into `MainLayout` content area? Or inside of `AppLayout` I may only add something to `Header` and `Drawer` only? How to properly implement such common tabs for these 3 views ? Right now I added duplicates of these tabs into each of the view and they don't work as expected(incorrect highlighting of selected tab). How to make them common for 3 views ?

Comment: You can use multiple parent layouts. See the official documentation for an example https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/routing/layout/#multiple-parent-layouts

Comment: Can you please add an answer how you solved it? This may be helpful for others

Comment: Sure, added the answer

Answer (score 0):

I created one more layout class with `@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class)` annotation and derived from `VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout`. Inside this layout I added my tabs. Now, for each of the mentioned in the question views, I use this new Layout.